# Twitter bootstrap modal hidden event only fires once

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I'm using a page with a single modal defined on it ("#agenda-modal").
When a trigger (.agenda-item) is clicked, I'm showing this modal with remote content like so:

```
$("body").on("click", ".agenda-question", function(e){
  var url = <build my url here>;
  $("#agenda-modal").modal({
    remote: url
  });
});
```

This works fine (I'm using listening to $body.on because .agenda-items are added via javascript).

When the modal is closed, I want to reload a part of the page (the part that the form inside the modal modifies).  So I'm using:

```
$("#agenda-modal").on("hidden", function(){
  alert("hidden");
});
```

Of course, all wrapped up in

```
$(function() {...});
```

This works, but only once!  When I first load the page and click a trigger, the modal loads up & when I close the modal the alert happens.  If I click the same trigger again, the modal shows up again but this time when it closes the alert does not happen!

I don't know, but is this because the listener - on("hidden", function...) - is not "bound" anymore?  I thought .on will always catch the event?

The code for the modal is straight off twitter:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="agenda-modal">
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?  I really want to catch when a modal closes so that I can update the part of the page that would have been changed.

Using rails btw, not sure if that matters...

Comment: What's your browser?, some browser's turn off alerts for the page after the first..

Comment: It's firefox, I've seen it do that - it will ask me if I want to stop further alerts but that's generally after 5 or so.  Also tested in IE 9 with same result.

Answer (score 11):

change

```
$("#agenda-modal").on("hidden", function() {
  alert("hidden");
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#agenda-modal', function () {    
  alert("hidden");
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that this fixes the issue.

Comment: Best solution IMO!

Answer (score 2):

### This is a known issue with Bootstrap

The issue is the event needs to be re-added every time it is fired, but on a delay.

Here is an example:

```
function hiddenModal() {
    alert("hidden");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#agenda-modal").on("hidden", hiddenModal );
    }, 222);
}

$("#agenda-modal").on("hidden", hiddenModal );
```

---

This is similar to another question, but for a different kind of event:

- [Radio buttons change() event only firing once when using $().button('reset')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459184/radio-buttons-change-event-only-firing-once-when-using-buttonreset)

Comment: Can you provide a link to somewhere where this bug/feature is documented as officially a 'known issue'?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure this out - everything looks OK, but there's a fair amount of js being added by the rails pipeline so I couldn't exclude the possibility something was interfering with my js.

Now using jquery's native modals instead.