# Radio buttons change() event only firing once when using $().button('reset')

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've created a button group with 3 radio buttons inside. They act as toggle buttons by using the bootstrap JavaScript (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons). I also want to show a loading state when a button is pressed (while an Ajax request is executing), so I'm using `$().button('loading')`.

Example code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=option]').change(function() {
    var $label = $(this).parent();
    $label.button('loading');

    // Perform Ajax request, simulated with timeout here
    setTimeout(function() {
      $label.button('reset');
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

At first sight it works, but after pressing all buttons once, then none of the buttons will fire the change-event anymore. This has something to do with the `$().button('reset')` I'm using, because after omitting that it works perfectly.

Here's a JS Bin I've created: http://jsbin.com/etaMURU/2/edit

Is that a Bootstrap bug or am I simply using the API wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed by delegating these events to the inputs as they are removed and re-injected into the DOM every time you set the button state to loading.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn-group').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=option]', function() {
    var $label = $(this).parent();
    $label.button('loading');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $label.button('reset');
    }, 2000);

    console.log('changed');
  });
});
```